# Go AWS Lambda: Where is event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

Most Lambda runtimes have the following handler signature, which allows accessing both the event and context objects passed into the Lambda:

```
lambdaHandler(event, context){}
```

However the documentation for Go Lambda handlers does not follow this convention as shown here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html

Question: How does one access the event object when using the Go Lambda runtime, i.e., when trying to determine the repository URL in an AWS CodeCommit Lambda Trigger (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-notify-lambda.html)?

Comment: The event object is the second parameter to the handler in the documentation you linked to. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: The documentation shows event being a struct defined within the uploaded Lambda consisting of only a "name" property - not the typical event object that contains event specifics passed in from the trigger.

Comment: That is the event object for the example. You'll need to use a struct that matches the fields of whatever type of event you're handling.

Comment: Adrian, see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected event is of type `events.CodeCommitEvent`

```golang
func handler(ctx context.Context, codeEvent events.CodeCommitEvent) {
    for _, record := range codeEvent.Records {
        // do you magic here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: @JTW Hope this works for you https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/tree/master/events

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I was looking for!